# Multiple Bills Printing in C#

Tags: c#-2.0

I am developing a module in a billing system for a national Utility. The module is supposed to pick all successfully billed customers and print their bills.Bills are written as text files and saved on a local folder and the program has to pick them up and print them one by one.I'm using a DFX-9000 printer and pre-formatted roll paper,however,each time a new bill comes in,the printer skips some space before it prints it which distorts the 2nd and following bills.
I tried putting all the bills in a single text file which prints well when opened in notepad but not in my code.
Here is part of my code

```
Font printFont = new Font("Lucida Console", 10);
    //static string filename;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Filename);
    public void Print()
    {
        try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("myPaper", 826, 1169);
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            //pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterSettings.IsPlotter = true;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrinterResolution.Kind = PrinterResolutionKind.Custom;
            pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(this.PrintTextFileHandler);
            pd.Print();
            if (reader != null)
                reader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Printout Complete");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    private void PrintTextFileHandler(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs pe)
    {
        StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        float linesPerPage = 0;
        float yPos = 0;
        int count = 0;
        float leftMargin = 40;//pe.MarginBounds.Left;
        float topMargin = pe.MarginBounds.Top;
        string line = null;
        linesPerPage = 500;// pe.MarginBounds.Height / printFont.GetHeight(g);
        while (count <= linesPerPage &&((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null))
        {
            yPos = topMargin + (count * printFont.GetHeight(g));
            g.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black, leftMargin, yPos);
            count++;
        }

        if (line != null)
        {
            pe.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        else
        {
            pe.HasMorePages = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could your printing.papersize be wrong? I notice it's 1169, doesn't standard paper stop at 1100?

Comment: Thing is if I print a single bill it looks fine but trouble comes when i try to print more than 1..I'm thinking I need to create one file with an infinite height with correct spacing after each specific bill so that the printer sees it as one page

Comment: So if you reduce the size to 1100, do lines get cut off?